# How do I forward my passport js credentials to GitHub?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, github-api

I am using passport.js with the GitHub strategy for authenticating users. I have successfully implemented user sign-in and I can query the credentials of the current user on the server (`req.user`).

Now I want to be able to use the GitHub api from my application. Due to CORS, my setup is this:

```
User Action <-> GET / POST <-> My Web Server <-> GET / POST <-> GitHub
```

The problem is that my web server needs to pass the user's credentials when making requests to GitHub on their behalf.

How do I "foward" my user session to GitHub?

I am using `superagent` on my server to call the GitHub API.

Comment: Related discussion: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/react-production-starter/issues/37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to solving this. First, you need to store the user's access-token when GitHub triggers the callback:

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: gitHubClientId,
    clientSecret: gitHubClientSecret,
    callbackURL: gitHubCallback
  },
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
    cb(null, {accessToken, profile}); // Note that we serialize the access-token
  }
));
```

Next, you need to include the access-token in your requests to GitHub. For example, to create a new Gist:

```
request.post('https://api.github.com/gists')
  .set('Authorization', 'Token ' + req.user.accessToken) // This is the important bit!
  .send(newGist)
  .end((error, result) => {
    console.log(error, result);
  });
```